# How can I add I-CUBE-LRWAN libraries to a new project?

Tags: stm32, lora, lorawan, cubemx

I am working with STM32 B-L072Z-LRWAN1 discovery kit. How can I add I-CUBE-LRWAN libraries externally, after i have created a project on CubeMX for B-L072Z-LRWAN1 discovery kit. Because project which i have created have not radio libraries. I am coding with System Workbench. 
Before this project, i used Ping-Pong example. It was divergent for create a fresh project. So i am trying to make a new project for Lora.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: hey what happend? you unaccepted the answer. Did you come up with a better one or was it plain wrong?

Comment: hello my friend, i have applied to your answer but unfortunately i can't make it work. So i uncheck it for now  for possible visitors.

Comment: Could you post your project structure for reference?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer it from te point of view of a Keil project because that is the program wherein I've done it but these steps should be interchangeable with the IDE. It mostly involves copying the code and adding the right linker and source paths.

The I-CUBE-LRWAN project has been setup such as that the parts of the project have been separated. The root directory of the project consists of three folders: `Middlewares`, `Projects` and `Drivers`. These folders contain both `.h` and `.c` files inside their tree structure.

## Drivers

The `Drivers` folder contains all the files related to the specific board you are using, the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer), [CMSIS](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/cmsis) and the BSP (Board Support Package). The HAL and CMSIS provide a generalized interface towards the device and when using these creates code that can be ported to other STM32 platforms by changing out the CMSIS board specific definitions. I would recommend that when you create a project you tick the box to include all library files in your project. This will make compilation take longer and your project bigger but will also prevent you from fussing about with missing libraries. The BSP contains Board Specific interfaces for interfaces present on your platform. This includes LEDs and buttons on the L072Z-LRWAN1 and in case of the STM32l4 nucleo the joystick/LCD.
I would recommend that you copy your board specific BSP (`.h` and `.c`) into your project and use them as a standardized interface to board specific features. You should create a new BSP `.h/.c` pair when you are using a custom board.

## Projects

The `Projects` contains your project specific code and contains the business end of your application. A bit of a bump in the road comes up here as ST has chosen to implement all their LoRaWAN code inside the `main.c` file. I would recommend that you take out all the LoRaWAN related initialization and transmission code (generally anything related to `LoRaMainCallback_t`) and put it inside a separate file with a defined interface. This is a bit of work but will pay dividend in the fact that your normal code has been separated from your LoRaWAN handling. I've stored my LoRaWAN code inside the file `lorawan.<h|c>`. With regard to the rest of the files: move the contents to a separate folders in your project called `LoRaWAN/App/inc/` and `LoRaWAN/App/src/`. This pertains to the files: `debug.c`, `hw_gpio.c`, `hw_rtc.c`, `hw_rtc.c`, `vcom.c`, `debug.h`, `hw.h`, `hw_conf.h`, `hw_gpio.h`, `hw_msp.h`, `hw_rtc.h`, `hw_spi.h`, `utilities_conf.h` and `vcom.h`. Add the `inc` folder to your include path (the `-I` option) and the source files to your project.

## Middlewares

The `Middlewares` folder needs to be copied from the source project to your target project and every `inc` folder or folder with `.h` files needs to be added to your include path and every source file needs to be added to your project. I would recommend that the folder structure is kept inside your IDE as to make your navigation between project and folder structure easier.
[image: example of matching structure]

Another postive effect of keeping the folder structures similar is that upgrading your code with a newer stack should be easier as the files can be found in a somewhat same place in both projects.

## Preprocessor defines

And a most important step. You need to take the `DEFINE` parameters defined inside the project and copy the into your own project. This can be found inside the Keil project (and the other projects also but in other places) under: `options for target x`->`C/C++`->`define`. It contains something akin to these values: `STM32L072xx,USE_B_<board name>,USE_HAL_DRIVER,REGION_EU868,DEBUG,TRACE`. As you can see I'm using: a Murata radio with integrated STM32, the EU 868 region and debugging and tracing options.

It should be possible to include "hw.h" and compile your program when you've done everything right.

Comment: Thank you very much Tarick for your answer. I think it proper Truestudio as well.

Comment: If answer is a good answer and/or the accepted one then please [vote the answer up and/or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This rewards both you and me and makes it clear to others what the best answer is.